# The story abou Imam Abu-Hanifa (where he said Alhamdulillah twice about his ship)

Tags: source-identification

One afternoon Imam Abu-Hanifa was teaching when a man came and told him that his ship sunk. The Imam paused for a moment and said Alhamdulillah; later the same man came and said there had been a mistake, and, again the Imam paused than said Alhamdulillah.

(Later the Imam said that the first time he said Alhamdulillah because he realized in his heart there was no sorrow of any kind, and later he realized that in his heart there was no happiness of any kind also, so he praised Allah for making him not attached to worldly matters.)

What is the most authentic source of this incident?

Comment: I've never heard this story before.